# Migrating from Python 2.7 to 3.4 token generator encoding

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, character-encoding

I'm working on an old project of mine, and I decided to try out python 3, specifically 3.4.

I'm building in the Pyramid framework and I need to generate a randomized for authentication purposes. Previously I just added a random bit to the user id and all was fine, but with python 3 I'm having some encoding troubles.

This is how I used to do it:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from Crypto.Hash import HMAC, SHA

def create_token(request, username):

    r = uuid4().hex + b64encode(json.dumps({'username': username}))

    sig = HMAC.new(secret, r.encode('UTF-8'), SHA).hexdigest()
    return u"{}{}".format(sig, r)
```

But now I get the error:

```
  File "/security.py", line 30, in create_token
    r = uuid4().hex + b64encode(json.dumps({'username': username}))
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.4.0/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 63, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

So I tried encoding the username, and I get

```
TypeError: b'admin' is not JSON serializable
```

So the encoder wants bytes and JSON want strings, how can I make this work in python 3?

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match your posted function. There is no `userid` in your posted code, for example.

Comment: Changed userid to username rather

Comment: That doesn't make your traceback match yet though. The `userid` line in the traceback looks like it is part of a larger dictionary statement over multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, I modified the code so it was clearer for me what exactly was causing the error. It's still the same code, but I'll edit it to be more consistent.

Comment: Thanks, just making sure we don't miss something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires strings, and encoding to JSON produces a string, but `b64ecode()` requires bytes. Encode the output of `json.dumps()`:

```
encoded_json = json.dumps({'username': username})
r = uuid4().hex + b64encode(encoded_json.encode('utf8')).decode('ascii')
```

Note that the `b64encode()` function produces bytes too, so you'd have to decode those if you wanted to concatenate this with the UUID hex.

Comment: Well it it worked allright, but now on the return I'm getting another error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`. But there aren't any bytes in the sig, secret is a string. Here's a pastebin http://pastebin.com/JAXunsG0

Comment: @Niel: Your `secret` must by bytes too; that error indicates it is not.

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you very much.